# i want apply JSON.parse(school) only in school property. How will i achieve this in array of object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, ecmascript-6

```
let obj = [
  {
    name: "Manish",
    school: "{"name":"modal","email":"gmail"}",
    id: 21,
    stats: true,
    user_id: 2,
},
{
    name: "Ramesh",
    school: "{"name":"kamla","email":"yahoo"}",
    id: 10,
    stats: true,
    user_id: 3,
}]
```

Hello, I want to convert school property into an object. Kindly guide me. Thank you

Comment: use `obj.forEach` to iterate over all in your array, and `JSON.parse()` to parse the `school`  string

Comment: You tagged the question with `json`. So... Did you find something online how to convert JSON into an actual object?

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: The `obj` is not valid JS. May you make sure you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

What you entered wasn't valid JavaScript. When you include a quote (`"`) in a string, you need to escape it with a slash so that it knows how to differentiate between the start and the end of the string and the quote contained in your string - like this: `"string containing \"quotes\""`

But assuming you meant to properly escape the JSON strings, you could try this:

```js
let objects = [
  {
    name: "Manish",
    school: "{\"name\":\"modal\",\"email\":\"gmail\"}",
    id: 21,
    stats: true,
    user_id: 2,
  },
  {
    name: "Ramesh",
    school: "{\"name\":\"kamla\",\"email\":\"yahoo\"}",
    id: 10,
    stats: true,
    user_id: 3,
  },
];

const converted = objects.map((item) => ({
  ...item, school: JSON.parse(item.school)
}));

console.log(converted);
```

Answer (score -1):

try this code  ==>

```
JSON.parse(obj[1].school)
```

```js
let obj = [
  {
    name: "Manish",
    school: '{"name":"modal","email":"gmail"}',
    id: 21,
    stats: true,
    user_id: 2,
},
{
    name: "Ramesh",
    school: '{"name":"kamla","email":"yahoo"}',
    id: 10,
    stats: true,
    user_id: 3,
}]

for (var i = 0 ; i < obj.length ; i++){

obj[i].school = JSON.parse(obj[i].school)
}
console.log(obj[0])
console.log(obj[1])
```

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: i want apply JSON.parse(school) only in school property. How will i achieve this in array of object?

Comment: this code will change the school property only to an object , and you can put it in a loop to get all school properties